# What happens to pictures, videos and audio messages in recipients inbox when facebook account is deleted?

Tags: facebook

If you delete a Facebook account, messages will still be visible in recipient's inbox, showing their own name. But: What happens to pictures, videos and audio messages in recipients inbox when facebook account is deleted?

Answer (score 2):

Everything remains accessible to the recipient: regardless of the scenario (deactivating your facebook, deleting your facebook, clearing your inbox), you can only impact your own inbox, not the inbox of other users. Thus, they will still be able to access the old messages, pictures, and videos in their inbox.